# How to convert response header in array in php

Tags: php, regex, parsing, http-headers

I am using Gcm for sending notifications and I have used curl for the same. Here is the script

```
$registrationId=  array('adkbvkasdjb');
$headers=array(
    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$sendData=array(
    'msg'=>'any message');
$url= GCM_URL;

$details=array( 
    'registration_ids'=>$registrationId,
    'time_to_live'=> 48*60*60,
    'data'=>$sendData,
);
$ch=  curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($details));

$result=  curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);

$body = substr($result, $header_size);

// closing the curl connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Now i am getting the header of the response as

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 11:05:17 GMT
Expires: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 11:05:17 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Since I am not very good with regex and i searched a lot about a method that could parse the header of the response but all in vain.

**Question:-**
 So i just wanna know is there anything or any method that could parse the header response as an array ?

**Note:-** I found a little about `http_parse_header()` but it need pcre to be installed so i am not sure whether it is installed on my REAL SERVER :)

Comment: Couldn't you just split by newline and :

Comment: Headers are separate by `\r\n` in the HTTP spec

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any Regex to do it. If you read the first comment of parse_http_headers documentation on php.net, there is a little implementation if pecl_http lib is not found.
Follow the link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php#112986